# Android: Intellij Buttom nav template creates unused space, hides nodes under it

Tags: android, android-studio, templates, intellij-idea, navigation

I created an Android project in Intellij with the buttom nav template.
I can not use a certain space on the top (see screenshot) which corelates in size with the buttom nav bar, even though the constrains seem to be right.
As well it hides/converes elements which are placed under it, actually there is a TextView and a spinner.
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view" android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the fragment height from `wrap_content` to `0dp` i.e `match_constraint` (`match_parent`)

[match_constraint or 0dp](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) : The view expands as much as possible to meet the constraints on each side (after accounting for the view's margins).

[Chain](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/images/constraint-chain-styles_2x.png): A chain is a group of views that are linked to each other with bi-directional position constraints. The views within a chain can be distributed either vertically or horizontally. For your case we need a Vertical Chain. See [video](https://developer.android.com/images/training/constraint-layout/constraint-layout-chain.mov)

And last I remove the `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` from you `ConstraintLayout`

**Try the below code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Oweee this answer worked!
May you explain a bit what you did and what my flaw was so I can mark your answer as correct?

Comment: @pikkuez you just have to use 0dp (`match_constraint` like `match_parent` ) for fragment height. And I assign the vertical chain to both `fragment` and the `BottomNavigation` that's it. Please see the updated answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

from your root ConstraintLayout.